# AWS Lambda Docker Image: OSError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-linux

I am creating an image for an AWS Lambda function based on `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10` image. However, as I can understand, the image comes with `glibc_2.26` installed. My function has a dependency on `glibc_2.29`. I know that creating a custom image based on `python:3.10` for example would solve the issue, but I was looking if there is a solution to somehow use the official Lambda image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amazon Linux 2023 is now available](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/amazon-linux-2023/), and [it has upgraded `glibc`, `gcc` and `binutils`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/compare-with-al2.html#glibc-gcc-and-binutils.). Hooray!